# ADT and GCC both on eclipse together

Tags: eclipse, opencv, gcc

I am 15 years so I may seem to be a noob. I have eclipse on Windows 8.1 64-bit with the android development add-on and have been using it for 3 months now. I have followed the following tutorial to install MinGW on eclipse:

http://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/mingweclipse/mingweclipse.html

I am not able to see the top right option for C/C++. It only shows Java. Is the ADT bundle interfering or is it something else.

Just for your info. I am using C/C++ for OpenCV and I dont want to use Visual Studio.
If there isnt any solution, I will go with VS, but if there is, it will save me a lot of time and money.

Thanks,
Rochan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You need the Eclipse CDT/C++ addon](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) which that article doesn't seem to tell you

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply. Real time saver.